# Get values from database with only 2 decimal places using MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, decimal

I want to retrieve values from a table with figures formatted in float. The decimal places range up to thirteen. I only want to retrieve the rows whose values only have exactly 2 decimal places. How do I do this?

Expected output:

```
[45.678, 56.236656457, 89.23, 100.89] ==> [89.23, 100.89]
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You want all values rounded to 2 decimal places, or all values that are exact to 2 decimal places (i.e. an integer when multiplied by 100)

Comment: @Nick I need to retrieve the values that only have exactly 2 decimal places. The column contains figures with decimal places that can range from 1 to 13, but I only need to retrieve those that have exactly 2. (e.g. [45.678, 56.236656457, 89.23, 100.89] ==> [89.23, 100.89])

Comment: @Nick I updated the question, kindly refer to it for an expected output.

Comment: There isn't really any practical way to do this because of the imprecision of floating point. For example, your values of 89.23 and 100.89 are not exactly representable in floating point, so the values in the table don't actually meet your criteria. You'll probably need to change your column datatype to something like `DECIMAL(20,13)` to be able to do what you want.

Comment: It's an unusual request- just saying

Comment: If you were using `DECIMAL` datatype, there would be practical ways to achieve your goal.  If the numbers were in strings, ditto.  But `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are impractical.  Where does 45.678 come from?  That is, show us how the input was generated/fetched/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select Length(123.12 % 1) - 2` to get the length of the values after the decimal.

`select (123.12 % 1)` returns `0.12` so you always know that you have `0.` in your result set, you can then get the length of your value minus the two characters and only select the rows where length = 2.

Comment: I don't need to round off values. I only need to retrieve rows that have exactly 2 decimal places in a table column where they can range from 1 to 13.

Comment: Ok cool, have a look at the 2nd link posted, there is a truncate function and it is used i.e. TRUNCATE(123.456123, 2) = 123.45

Comment: I'm afraid truncate won't do the trick as well. The column contains figures with decimal places that can range from 1 to 13, but I only need to retrieve those that have exactly 2.
(e.g. [45.678, 56.236656457, 89.23, 100.89] ==> [89.23, 100.89])

Comment: I updated the question, kindly refer to it for an expected output.

Comment: Will you be able to use this: `select length(substring(123.123,INSTR(123.4564,'.')+1,13));` ?